# jquery if/else block problem

Tags: jquery

I'm having a problem with an if/else block.  The problem is that the else block is always executing. When the click happens, if two select elements have both have a class of "current-drop" then only the if block should execute.

However, since those two classes are being removed at the end of the if block (the classes are added again later using the `change()` method) then I suppose that is causing the else block to execute. Is it because the click event isn't finished firing when the classes are removed, causing the conditions to change?

How can I work around this?

```
$('.add-button').click(function() {

var class1=$("#select-pub").attr('class');
var class2=$("#select-segment").attr('class');

if ((class1=='current-drop') && (class2=='current-drop')) {

    $('<li />', {text: $('#select-pub option:selected').text()})
    .appendTo('div #publisher-results ul');
    $('<li />', {text: $('#select-segment option:selected').text()})
    .appendTo('div #segment-results ul');
    $('#select-pub').removeClass('current-drop');
    $('#select-segment').removeClass('current-drop');
    $('#error-message').css('visibility','hidden');
}

else
{
    $('#error-message').css('visibility','visible');
}

});
```

edit: Here is the page - yes I know it is a bit of a soupy mess right now...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Group Commerce | Dashboard</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css"/>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/add-items-over.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {


    $("a#click-up").fancybox({
        'padding':0,
        'margin':0,
        'scrolling':'no',
        'showCloseButon':'true',
        'overlayColor':'#dfdfdf'
        });



});
</script>



 <style type="text/css">
        /* Custom Theme */


        h1 {font-family:verdana;font-size:18px; color:#122652;padding:30px 0 0 20px;}

        table {width:577px;margin-left:20px;
        border:1px solid #d5d5d5;font-family:arial; font-size:11px;}

        table td {
            border-right:1px solid #d5d5d5;
            padding:5px 0 5px 5px;
            }

        tr.table-bg td {
            border-bottom:1px solid #d5d5d5;
            font-weight:bold;
            background:url(images/table-top-bg.jpg) repeat-x;
            }

        #modal-left {
            width:272px;
            margin-top:-11px;
            float:left;
            }

        #modal-right {
            width:335px;
            float:right;
            margin-top:-11px;
            }

            #error-message {
            margin-bottom:15px;

        margin-left:20px;
            margin-top:5px;
            }

            .error-default {
                color:red;
                }

            .error-message-no {
                visibility:hidden !important;
                }

        .error-message-yes {
                visibility:visible;
                }

        #modal-left p {
            margin-left:20px;
            }

        #modal-left a, #modal-right a {
            background:url(images/add-select.gif) no-repeat;
            margin-top:-1px;
            }

        #modal-left a {
            position:relative;
            right:2px;
            }



            .select-div {
                width:272px;
                float:left;
                }

            .link-div {
                width:46px;
                height:22px;
                float:right;
                margin-top:30px;
                }

            #modal-left select {
            margin-left:20px;
            width:252px;
            }

            #publisher-results {
                background-color:#f9f9f9;
                width:252px;
                height:100px;
                margin-left:20px;
                margin-top:5px;
                }

            #segment-results {
                background-color:#f9f9f9;
                width:252px;
                height:100px;
                margin-top:3px;
                }

            .select-div2 {
                width:220px;
                float:left;
                }

            .select-div2 select {
                width:252px;
                }

            .link-div2 {
                width:46px;
                height:22px;
                float:right;
                position:relative;
                right:22px;
                }

            #modal-right a {
            background:url(images/add-select.gif) no-repeat;
            position:relative;
            right:2px;
            }

            #publisher-results {
                overflow:hidden;
                }

            #publisher-results ul {
                margin-top:5px !important;
                }

            #publisher-results li {
                list-style:none;
                position:relative;
                right:30px;
                margin-bottom:3px;
                }

            #segment-results {
                overflow:hidden;
                }

            #segment-results ul {
                margin-top:5px !important;
                }

            #segment-results li {
                list-style:none;
                position:relative;
                right:30px;
                margin-bottom:3px;
                }

            #footer {
                text-align:right;
                margin-top:150px;
                width:100%;
                padding-right:30px;
                }

            #footer-submit  {
                display:block;
                float:right;
                width:116px;
                height:22px;
                background:url(images/submit-to-copy.gif) no-repeat;
                position:relative;
                right:12px;
                margin-left:10px;
                }

            #footer-cancel {
                display:block;
                float:right;
                width:68px;
                height:22px;
                background:url(images/cancel.gif) no-repeat;
                position:relative;
                right:12px;
                }
            #box-content {
                border:1px solid white;
                }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="modal-wrap">
<a id="click-up" href="#box-content">Click here for popup</a>

<div style="display:none;">
<div id="box-content" style="width:620px;height:335px;background:url(images/modal-bg.gif) left top no-repeat;">
<h1>Send the following deal to copy stage...</h1>

<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr class="table-bg">
<td>Vendor</td>
<td>Vendor ID</td>
<td style="width:100px;">Offer</td>
<td>Status</td>
<td>Availability Start</td>
<td style="border-right:none;">Availability End</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Apple</td>
<td>10010000111</td>
<td>$2.99 app</td>
<td>Ready for Market</td>
<td>9/20/2010</td>
<td style="border-right:none;">9/20/2010</td>
</tr>
</table>

<p id="error-message"><em>Both the publisher and the segment fields are required!</em></p>
<div id="modal-left">



<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#error-message').addClass('error-default');
$('#select-pub').change(function() {
$(this).addClass('current-drop');
}); 

$('#select-segment').change(function() {
$(this).addClass('current-drop');
}); 


$('.add-button').click(function() {

var class1=$("#select-pub").attr('class');
var class2=$("#select-segment").attr('class');
if ($('#select-pub').hasClass('current-drop') && $('#select-segment').hasClass('current-drop')) {

    $('<li />', {text: $('#select-pub option:selected').text()})
    .appendTo('div #publisher-results ul');
    $('<li />', {text: $('#select-segment option:selected').text()})
    .appendTo('div #segment-results ul');
    $('#select-pub').removeClass('current-drop');
    $('#select-segment').removeClass('current-drop');
    $('#error-message').css('visibility','hidden');
    }

    /*else
    {
    $('#error-message').css('visibility','visible');
    }*/

});
});

</script>



<div class="select-div">

<select id="select-pub">
<option val="1" selected>Publisher 1</option>
<option val="2">Publisher 2</option>
<option val="3">Publisher 3</option>
<option val="4">Publisher 4</option>
</select> 

</div>

<!--<div class="link-div">
<a class="add-button" href="#" style="width:46px;height:22px;display:block;"></a>
</div>-->

<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div id="publisher-results">
<ul>
</ul>
</div>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$('.add-button-2').click(function() {
$('<li />', {text: $('#select-segment option:selected').text()})
.appendTo('#segment-results ul');
$('#segment-results ul li:odd').css('display','none');
});

});

</script>
<div id="modal-right">

<div class="select-div2">
<select id="select-segment">

<option selected>Segment 1</option>
<option>Segment 2</option>
<option>Segment 3</option>
<option>Segment 4</option>
</select>

</div>

<div class="link-div2">
<a href="#" class="add-button" style="width:46px;height:22px;display:block;"></a>
</div>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div id="segment-results">
<ul style="margin:0;">
</ul>
</div>

</div>

<div id="footer">

<a href="#" id="footer-submit"></a>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="$.fancybox.close();" id="footer-cancel"></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The else block cannot execute concurrently if the if block is already executing. Do you have multiple classes in your selects? If so, you shouldn't use `attr('class')` to query classes.

Comment: Can you also post your HTML? An error in your HTML (a missing quote, for example) will cause the jQuery to always go into the else statement, but due to browser robustness, your website will look fine.

Comment: No multiple classes, only id's for each select.  The div id "error-message" is getting the css in the else block no matter what the conditions are. If I remove the else block, the #error-message gets the correct css.

Comment: I have posted the html...and am checking it for errors. That sounds like it might be the problem...I can't otherwise see why it's going into the else block.

Comment: I can't for the life of me figure out why the else block is firing. I put the code in a validator and cleaned up a few things and no joy.

Comment: @johnyb - Check out my response...did you find the missing div tag? That may be screwing things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you posted your code (thank you), I tidied up the HTML. It looks like you are missing a closing `<div>` tag somewhere which could cause you problems. As far as I can see, your jQuery is right - so my guess is on the HTML. (I would look for quotes as well as matching brackets.)

Comment: I just put the script in the page head and it worked! No idea why that would be.

Comment: @johnnyb - Ahhh...you probably reference something that wasn't defined until later (when you had your Javascript lower). My suggestion, however, is that you encapsulate your scripts in a separate file. Keeping them in the head incurrs slower loading times and does not take advantage of caching. Glad your problem was fixed!

Answer (score 6):

If you have any other classes on those elements, it will always fail.  Revise the `if` part to:

```
if($('#select-pub').hasClass('current-drop') && $('#select-segment').hasClass('current-drop')) {
...
```

Comment: Did this, but didn't change anything. Else block is still executing.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at what the values of class1 and class2 are, before hitting the if/else block.  Use an alert() or console.log().